# Bus error when returning double from assembly program

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm, sse, bus-error

I'm trying to write a program exactly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730543/assembly-64bit-how-to-return-a-double-value). The only difference is that I'm using the stack memory instead of the .bss section to hold the value I'm getting from the calling function.
After this change, I'm getting Bus Error when returning from the assembly function.

Any ideas why?

C-program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern double func(double d);
int main(){
  double d_1 = 1.22;
  double d_2 = func(d_1);
  printf("%lf\n", d_2);
  return 0;
}
```

Assembly:

```
section .text
global func
func:
enter   0,0
sub     rsp, 8
movq    qword[rbp],xmm0  ; Store current value in memory  
fld     qword[rbp]       ; Load current value from memory
fld     qword[rbp]       ; Load current value from memory again
fadd                     ; Add top two stack items
leave
ret
```

Comment: What instruction exactly do you get the bus error on?  What values are in registers?  Also, in both mainstream x86-64 calling conventions, `double` is returned in `xmm0`.  Use `addsd xmm0,xmm0` / `ret` like a normal person.  Or if you insist on x87, then `fld` / `fadd st0, st0`

Comment: I didn't have a clue about the addsd thing so this is a great help :-) What excatly it does? And the error occures when trying to pass $rax to a local variable in main. namely: mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)

Comment: Also, `enter` is slow; compilers avoid it for a reason, and just use `push rbp` / `mov rbp,rsp` if they don't omit the stack frame entirely and just use registers or stack space relative to RSP..  `enter` is 12 uops on Skylake, with a throughput of one per 8 cycles (http://agner.org/optimize/), vs. push+mov only being 2 uops with a tiny throughput impact.  But if you *are* going to use `enter` (for code-size reasons?), use a non-zero immediate so you don't also need `sub rsp, 8` right after.

Comment: Use `si` step *into* functions, not over them.  GDB will tell you what address RIP had when a signal was received.  (`addsd` is mentioned in an answer on the question you linked.  Look at any x86 instruction reference manual, like http://felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html or other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Comment: If you're programming in NASM, you should use GDB's `set disassembly-flavor intel` to get GAS / binutil's  MASM-like syntax.  See debugging tips at the bottom of the tag wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movq  [rbp],xmm0` overwrites the saved RBP value that `enter` pushed.  This would be more obvious if you hadn't used `enter`, but `[rbp+0]` is not an address you can use in a function with a stack frame.

(`[rbp-8]` is the highest address you can use for locals.  `[rsp]` would have worked, because you decremented RSP after `enter` set RBP=RSP, but you used RBP.)

---

When execution returns to `main`, `gcc -O0` (anti-optimized for debugging) runs these instructions to store the function return value from `xmm0` into stack space for `d_2` instead of just passing it directly to `printf` while it's still in a register:

```
movq   rax,xmm0
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax    # Using RBP after you clobbered it.
```

Un-optimized gcc output is *really* silly: copying FP data to an integer register instead of storing directly with `movsd` makes no sense.  But that's not the issue.

---

**`RBP` holds the [IEEE `double` precision bit-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for `1.22` (`0x3ff3851eb851eb85`) because that's what your `func` clobbered it with.**

**The address `rbp-8` is not canonical**: the high 16 bits don't match bit 47, so it's not a sign-extended 48-bit virtual address.  (See [this ASCII-art diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977755/address-canonical-form-and-pointer-arithmetic)).

Using a non-canonical address on current x86-64 hardware generates a `#GP(0)` exception (according to [Intel's manual entry for `mov`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html)), and Linux maps this x86 exception to SIGBUS.

**This is why you get a bus error instead of the usual segmentation fault for trying to access unmapped memory with a bogus pointer.**

---

**Your code is over-complicated and wrong**

In both mainstream x86-64 calling conventions (Linux/OS X use x86-64 System V), `double` is returned in `xmm0`. Use [`addsd xmm0,xmm0`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADDSD.html) / `ret` like a normal person, like the answer on the question you linked shows.

```
func:
    addsd   xmm0,xmm0   ; first FP arg in (low 64 bits of) xmm0
    ret                 ; return value in (low 64 bits of) xmm0
```

Or if you insist on x87, then look how much code you have to write:

```
func:
    movsd  [rsp-8], xmm0      ; double arg in xmm0
    fld    qword [rsp-8]
    fadd   st0, st0           ; use x87 regs instead of uselessly loading twice.
    fstp   qword [rsp-8]      ; empty the x87 stack
    movsd  xmm0, [rsp-8]      ; return value in xmm0
    ret
```

That's using 8 bytes below RSP as scratch space, in the [red-zone](/questions/tagged/red-zone) to store/reload to get data between SSE2 registers and x87, because the x86-64 calling conventions are designed around SSE2, using xmm registers.  Use `sub rsp, 8` / `add rsp, 8` if you don't want to use the red-zone.

Don't use x87 in x86-64 unless you need 80-bit floating-point precision.

([`enter` is slow and not recommended](http://agner.org/optimize/); make a stack frame with `push rbp` / `mov rbp,rsp` if you want one.  `leave` is fine, though.  Making a stack frame is optional; I left that out.)

---

`printf` doesn't need `"%lf"` to print a `double`, only `scanf` needs `lf`.  You *can't* `printf` a single-precision float, because C default promotion rules apply to args of variadic functions, and thus any `float` is promoted to `double`.

In most C implementations (including glibc), `"%lf"` works anyway, silently ignoring the meaningless `l` modifier on the `%f` conversion.

I mention this in case you try to do that with `call printf` with a  `"%f"` format string from asm later, and run into [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082784/how-to-print-a-single-precision-float-with-printf).

Comment: Totally got it. The code runs. Thank you so much, you helped me a lot

Comment: Can you please explain how can I return an array of double precision values?

Comment: @RotemBarak: Same way you'd return an array of anything else.  If it's small and fixed-size, you could return a SIMD vector in `xmm0` (`__m128i func(double in)`), otherwise pass a pointer for the output.  `void func(double in, double *dst_pointer, size_t len)`

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot